# Regex matching the entire file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a big SRT (subtitle) file that I'm trying to convert to JSON, but my regex doesn't seem to be working correctly.

My expression:

```
^(\d+)\r?\n(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([.,]\d{1,3})?)\s*\-\-\>\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([.,]\d{1,3})?)\r?\n([\s\S]*)(\r?\n)*$
```

Here is a sample of my srt file, each subtitle follows the same scheme.

```
1
00:00:11,636 --> 00:00:13,221
Josh communicated but

2
00:00:13,221 --> 00:00:16,850
it's also the belief that
we never knew the severity
```

my javascript file

```
const fs = require('fs');
function parse(content, options) {
    var captions = [];
    var parts = content.split(/\r?\n\s+\r?\n/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var regex = /^(\d+)\r?\n(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([.,]\d{1,3})?)\s*\-\-\>\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([.,]\d{1,3})?)\r?\n([\s\S]*)(\r?\n)*$/gi;
        var match = regex.exec(parts[i]);
        if (match) {
            var caption = {};
            var eol = "\n";
            caption.id = parseInt(match[1]);
            caption.start = match[2];
            caption.end = match[4];
            var lines = match[6].split('/\r?\n/');
            caption.content = lines.join(eol);
            captions.push(caption);
            continue;
        }
    }
    return captions;
};

var content = fs.readFileSync('./English-SRT-CC.srt', 'utf8');
var captions = parse(content);
var json = JSON.stringify(captions, " ", 2);
console.log(json);
fs.writeFile("output.json", json, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("JSON file has been saved.");
});
```

And finally, here's my output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "start": "00:00:11,636",
    "end": "00:00:13,221",
    "content": "Josh communicated but\n\n2\n00:00:13,221 --> 00:00:16,850\n
// cut for shortness, it just continues the rest of the file inside "content"
```

My desired output?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "start": "00:00:11,636",
    "end": "00:00:13,221",
    "content": "Josh communicated but"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "start": "00:00:13,221",
    "end": "00:00:16,850",
    "content": "it's also the belief that\n we never knew the severity"
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QC9Grb/2)

Comment: Using regex to parse JSON is an all-around bad idea.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using regex to parse text from a local file, then parsing that to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex to match your text:

```
/\d+\n[0-9\:\,\-\>\s]{29}\n(.+|(\n[^\n]))+/g
```

I'll break it down in parts:

**Part 1: `\d+\n`**

This part matches any digits followed by exactly one newline character.

**Part 2: `[0-9\:\,\-\>\s]{29}\n`**

This part matches the included characters, with exact length of 29, which is the fixed format of, for example, `00:00:11,636 --> 00:00:13,221`, then followed by one newline character.

**Part 3: `(.+|(\n[^\n]))+`**

Now this part is important. I'll break it into sub-parts:

- `.+` is to match any character, except newline characters.
- `(\n[^\n])` is to match exactly one newline character that is NOT followed by another newline character. This is important to make multi-line subtitle matching possible. Without this, you can't match multi-line subtitles (because of the file structure, not because of regex limitation).

Wrapping them up with bracket `(...)+` is to let it match with multiple lines. This is how you can match multi-line subtitles.

**Part 4: `g`**

Use this to match more than 1 matches.

**Working code**

In accordance to this regexp, I have also used another way to parse it into your desired output, which is a lot easier and less complicated that your current approach.

You can see how you can utilise it:

```js
const text = `
1
00:00:11,636 --> 00:00:13,221
Josh communicated but

2
00:00:13,221 --> 00:00:16,850
it's also the belief that
we never knew the severity
`;

const regex = /\d+\n+[0-9\:\,\-\>\s]{29}\n(.+|(\n[^\n]))+/g;
const rawResult = text.match(regex);

console.log(rawResult);

const parsedResult = rawResult.map(chunk => {
  const [id, time, ...lines] = chunk.split(/\n/g);
  const [start, end] = time.split(/\s\-\-\>\s/);
  const content = lines.join('\n');
  return { id, start, end, content };
});

console.log(parsedResult);
```